# PHP Mkdir not working - Full permission

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, mkdir

Our server is a Linux Server with Debian 5, Apache2

This is a development server which we are doing testing on and as such we have setup world write permission on everything

Ive also set the umask in /etc/profile to 000

One particular PHP script loops through some images in a directory and attempts to make thumbnails in a sub directory

the PHP Error we receive is "Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: No such file or directory"

apache2 runs as user www-data, I can login as www-data and make directories and files and everything with no problem

the apache error log just says File does not exist

Any suggestions?

Comment: We have also increased the apache LogLevel to debug in httpd.conf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the path its trying to create there ? ie if its trying to create `/var/www/images/thumb/` then `/var/www/images/` needs to exist. It may also pay to enable recursive creation `mkdir(/var/www/images/thumbs, 0, true)`

Comment: no the path doesnt exist. This works fine on 2 other servers, we dont want to change the code, but I will test to see if it works

Comment: I dont mean the final path that its trying to create i.e. if its trying to create `thumbs` within the directory `/var/www/images` then `/var/www/images` would have to exist before it tried to make `thumbs`